# Row count comparison as a condition in model builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have got number of point layers with overlays.[image]

I need one layer consisting of points of both layers.

For each overlay area I need to delete points in one of the overlaying layers. I want to keep the points from the layer that contains more points in the area of overlay.

Therefore I am building a model, which clips points of both layers in the overlay area, finds the counts of clipped points in both layers and delete the points in the layer with lower point number in the overlay area.

How can I use the row counts to select the layer where to delete the points?

[image]

Comment: Can you edit the image to show what this overlay area would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Calculate Value Tool with the two counts as input to return the name of the dataset with the lesser count. If your expression were:

```
get_lesser(%Row Count(2)%, %Row Count%)
```

The code block would look like this:

`def get_lesser(x, y):
  if x > y:
    return 'clipPoints1.shp'
  else:
    return 'clipPoints2.shp'`

Then use the result of that calculation as a parameter to the Delete tool.

You may have to right click on the ouputs and specify them as Model Parameters to do this.

*Edit:*
Since it looks like those tools don't accept Strings as references to layers, you may have to do it in arcpy.
Using the arcmap python console, the following code worked for me, where TEST and test_data are the two point datasets, and Sections_Dissolve is an overlay layer with a single feature:

```
import arcpy

test_data = "test_data"
Sections_Dissolve = "Sections_Dissolve"
TEST = "TEST"

test_data_select = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(test_data, "INTERSECT", Sections_Dissolve, "", "NEW_SELECTION", "NOT_INVERT")
test_data_count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(test_data_select).getOutput(0))
TEST_select = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(TEST, "INTERSECT", Sections_Dissolve, "", "NEW_SELECTION", "NOT_INVERT")
TEST_count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(TEST_select).getOutput(0))

if test_data_count > TEST_count:
    del_feats = TEST_select
else:
    del_feats = test_data_select
arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management(del_feats)
```

You could modify this to use a Search Cursor to loop through your overlay layer if it has multiple features.

Comment: Instead of using a code block, you can use the equivalent `'clipPoints1.shp' if %Row Count(2)% > %Row Count% else 'clipPoints2.shp'`

Comment: But I have no idea how to use the string output as an input for the next tools in the model, like Delete or Erase.

Comment: It should work the same way you use row count as an input for calculate value. In model builder, right click and specify the value  derived from the Calculate Value tool as a Model Parameter, then use the connect tool to connect it to the Delete tool and select "Precondition", then in the Delete tool, use %output_value% (or whatever you named the result of Calculate Value to be) as the input.

Comment: Also, be sure to use Delete_Features (after using Select by Location with your overlay area), or Erase and not Delete, since you want to get rid of features within the dataset, not the dataset itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Erase tool does not allow me to use %output_value% (or maybe "%output_value%", if the variable stores string? - but makes no difference in this case) as a Input Features. I get ERROR 000732
Input Features: Dataset %output_value% does not exist or is not supported.